# Yii2 - ajax validation on submit only, client validation on change

Tags: yii, yii2

Is it possible to enable ajax validation on form submit only, and have client / JS validation on change / blur? So for example:

1. User inputs data and presses tab key : client validation should apply
2. User then submits form : ajax validation should apply
3. If validation is successful, proceed with normal form submit

Here is my ActiveForm config:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'login-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'validateOnBlur' => true,
    'validateOnChange' => true,
    'validateOnSubmit' => true,
]); ?>
```

Currently, when I focus out of a field, it will apply ajax validation as well - I do not want this.

Comment: what is the version of yii2 you are using? i just used the same settings and they call the ajax validation only once and onblur just calls the client validation

Comment: I am using version `2.0.13.1`. I have tried this on a login form. When I enter an email address and press the tab key, I can see in the console it has performed an AJAX call.

Comment: just try updating it to the latest `2.0.14.1` with `composer update` and then confirm

Comment: and when you say it triggers ajax validation on blur do you mean that you see reuest inside the network tab?

Comment: Just updated to `2.0.14.1` and same thing happens. Yes, I can see the request inside the network tab. To be honest I think this is by design, because there is no way to specify whether `validateOnChange` and `validateOnBlur` will apply to ajax or client validation - it applies to both by default.

Comment: can you replace your setting with the following and check `'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'validateOnSubmit' => true,`

Comment: i am confident it should work the way you want it to, just remove all other options and keep these only along with `id`

Comment: No, same thing happens. Did you try this with a login form, where username must be an email address? Then enter a valid email address and press tab.

Comment: Yes not login thou but contact form with the same above settings and and it has the email fireld in it , it sends request on **ONLY** submit, and validates with frontend validation client side on blur , are you using exactly these 3 settings and nothing extra, and after updating your framework did you removed all assets from the `web/assets` directory. if not do it once and then try again. it is working for me as you expect it to

Comment: wait you are using the `username` to be an `email` then you must be validating that email from the `DB` are you sure you are not sending any extra call to validate any existing email from the database?

Comment: Yes I have removed assets folder. I tried on default contact form with those exact 3 settings and same thing happens. Did you check your console for XHR request after tabbing out of the field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166005/discussion-between-muhammad-omer-aslam-and-gstar).

Comment: hey Omar do select the answer if it helped you out to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it the way you want it to work you need to submit the form via AJAX and it is required to attach a handler on `afterValidate` event. The handler will replace default form submission and is responsible for sending data to the server and displaying error messages if server validation fails. Displaying validation messages requires support on the controller side.

You can update the form `name/id` respectively in the script. and add the alerts in the error and incorrect server response. your form will be automatically saved via ajax call without reloading you can reset the form inside the success part.

Attach a handler to form:

```
$this->registerJs('$(\'#my-form\').on(\'afterValidate\', function () {
    var $yiiform = $(this);
    $.ajax({
            type: $yiiform.attr(\'method\'),
            url: $yiiform.attr(\'action\'),
            data: $yiiform.serializeArray(),
        }
    )
        .done(function(data) {
            if(data.success) {
                $yiiform.submit();
                // data is saved
            } else if (data.validation) {
                // server validation failed
                $yiiform.yiiActiveForm(\'updateMessages\', data.validation, true); // renders validation messages at appropriate places
                console.log("error on form"+data.validation);
            } else {
                console.log("incorrect server response");
                // incorrect server response
            }
        })
        .fail(function () {
            console.log("request failed");
            // request failed
        })

    return false; // prevent default form submission
})');
```

Just make sure you have your action coded like below

**`Controller action`**:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        //call model validate to trigger validation messages
        $model->validate();

        $result = [];

        // The code below comes from ActiveForm::validate(). We do not need to validate the model
        // again, as it was already validated by save(). Just collect the messages.
        foreach ($model->getErrors() as $attribute => $errors) {
            $result[\yii\helpers\Html::getInputId($model, $attribute)] = $errors;
        }
        if (!empty($result)) {
            return $this->asJson(['validation' => $result]);
        }

        return $this->asJson(['success' => true]);

    } elseif ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Form saved successfully');
        return $this->redirect('index');
    }

    return $this->render('form', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

And most important just initialize your form with the option `enableClientValidation` as `true` like below.

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'login-form',
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
]);
```

Comment: updated the answer @GSTAR,changed a few things
as we need to submit the form manually
replace the event `beforeSubmit` with `afterValidate` and change the sequence of the action code to validate separately on `ajax` request and `submit/save` the `model` on `post` request once the validation passes we can submit the form via `javasript` `.submit()` in the ajax `success` function
i just tested it
and the form submits if validation passes via ajax call
hope it helps you out